# Adding the value of a combobox to a hidden column when a user enters a new record in Access 2003

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have a table with a 'category' column, a form which hides the category column, and a combobox to filter the category, let's say R, C, and F.

I want to have the value of the comobox applied to the hidden 'category' column when a user enters a new record into the form.

Is there I way I can get an instance to the record as it's being entered and modify the data using VB? Or would I have to write a sort of `pop()` function and have it run `afterInsert` and then modify it that way? Can I even alter the table using VB like this?

Answer (score 0):

simplest answer is bind the category field to the combo box.
otherwise use the afterupdate event to do: me.category = combobox.value